# Converting double to date field using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, date

In ArcMap I have a table with a column with the date type yyyy-mm-dd, but after opening SQlite in QGIS, this column is written as a double type.

How do I convert data in the form of a number to a date in QGIS?

Comment: How does the value in the field look like? If blank, the data is probably lost. If something like `0.00000`, you may have a chance to retrieve them. Either `Refactor` tool or `to_date()` function in the field calculator would worth a try.

Comment: Have a read of http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date/ in particular the section of Real storage of date types, apparently the storage is days since *noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C.* with the fraction portion being the time as a decimal of 24 hours whereas python packed time is https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC)*  so it's not just a straight conversion. It might be better to do this *in* SQLLite using any one of the functions mentioned in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html